# Is IHubContext<THub> of SignalR thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, thread-safety, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have this action inside an ASP.NET MVC Core controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var timeManager = new TimerManager(() =>
    {
        _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", DataManager.GetData());
    });

    return Ok(new { Message = "Request completed" });
}
```

The `TimerManager` class looks like this:

```cs
public class TimerManager
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;
    private Action _action;

    public DateTime TimerStarted { get; }

    public TimerManager(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _timer = new Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 1000, 2000);
        TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Execute(object stateInfo)
    {
        _action();

        if ((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).Seconds > 60)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if calling `_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync()` will have concurrency problems. Is `IHubContext<THub>` and its methods thread-safe?

Comment: What do you mean by save and concurrency problems?

Comment: @Kiril1512 Race conditions, making the IHubContext object's internal state inconsistent..., that kind of things.

Comment: Could you please clarify how the answer you've accepted saying '`IHubContext  is a singleton.`' addresses your concerns `IHubContext object's internal state inconsistent...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IHubContext<THub>` safely with `Timer`.

`IHubContext<THub>` is a singleton:

> ```cs
> services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(IHubContext<>), typeof(HubContext<>));
> ```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c84e37f30def9ff0b2d12e877e3de6c283be6145/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/SignalRDependencyInjectionExtensions.cs#L26

Comment: `IHubContext<THub> is a singleton` I'm sorry, but how does the fact that it's the singleton instance makes its `SendAsync()` method thread-safe?